# Access Lookup Table for local custom field on Project Server?

Tags: rest, project-server

Scenario: a user has an .mpp project file they work with locally.  They set up a local custom text field to use a lookup table.  They then upload and save that file to a Project Server / PWA instance, and publish it.

Is there a way to access the lookup table for that field using the `/_api/ProjectServer/` REST endpoint?

I know already that I can see the values of local custom fields by getting tasks from

```
/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('project-id')/Tasks
```

and the local custom fields show up with internal names like

```
LocalCustom_x005f_Published_x005f_7c0ccd0ceb0aea1182667c7635fa5766_x005f_000039b78bbe4ceb82c4fa8c0b40003b
```

however, the value of a local custom text field that has been set up to use a lookup table is not a string of the display value of that lookup entry, it's an array with the internal name of the lookup table entry, so something like

```
["Entry_10fb560fc5c0e711a8f0e4a7a071ef48"]
```

So, clearly, if I can get a hold of the lookup table entries, I can find the entry by its internal name and get the display value.  However, if I try to get the lookup tables from

```
/_api/ProjectServer/LookupTables
```

I only get the *Enterprise* lookup tables.

So is there a way to get the lookup table associated with a *local* custom field in a project that has been uploaded to Project Server?

Answer (score 1):

As answered over on the [MS TechNet Project Server Forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/4804ad86-959a-4907-9065-32bd76ba7cdc/access-lookup-table-for-local-custom-field-on-project-server?forum=project2010custprog), you can get the lookup table of a local custom field by using the URL

```
https://<<PWA URL>>/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('<<ProjectID>>')/CustomFields('LocalCustom_Draft_f233fada2a0cea119bdad4258bf6958b_000039b78bbe4ceb82c4fa8c0b400033')/LookupTable/Entries
```

which, I discovered through playing around in Postman, can be shortened to use just the custom field's GUID without the `LocalCustom` prefix with the project ID, like:

```
https://<<PWA URL>>/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('<<ProjectID>>')/CustomFields('000039b78bbe4ceb82c4fa8c0b400033')/LookupTable/Entries
```